# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table"ratings" in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

When I execute the code it generates error that given bellow:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ratings" LINE 4:
> AVG("ratings"."rating") AS "avgRatings" FROM "gig_workers" A...
> ^  SQL state: 42P01
>
> Character: 3366

SQL:

```
SELECT "gig_workers".*,
       "gig_types"."id" AS "gig_types.id",
       "gig_types"."name" AS "gig_types.name",
       "gig_types"."qualifications" AS "gig_types.qualifications",
       "gig_types"."experience" AS "gig_types.experience",
       "gig_types"."pay_rate" AS "gig_types.pay_rate",
       "gig_types"."dress_code" AS "gig_types.dress_code",
       "gig_types"."active" AS "gig_types.active",
       "gig_types"."createdAt" AS "gig_types.createdAt",
       "gig_types"."updatedAt" AS "gig_types.updatedAt",
       "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"."gigWorkerId" AS "gig_types.gig_worker_type_rel.gigWorkerId",
       "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"."gigTypeId" AS "gig_types.gig_worker_type_rel.gigTypeId",
       "gig_worker_metas"."id" AS "gig_worker_metas.id",
       "gig_worker_metas"."gig_worker_id" AS "gig_worker_metas.gig_worker_id",
       "gig_worker_metas"."key" AS "gig_worker_metas.key",
       "gig_worker_metas"."value" AS "gig_worker_metas.value",
       "gig_worker_metas"."createdAt" AS "gig_worker_metas.createdAt",
       "gig_worker_metas"."updatedAt" AS "gig_worker_metas.updatedAt",
       "profile_photos"."id" AS "profile_photos.id",
       "profile_photos"."user_id" AS "profile_photos.user_id",
       "profile_photos"."url" AS "profile_photos.url",
       "profile_photos"."type" AS "profile_photos.type",
       "profile_photos"."case_id" AS "profile_photos.case_id",
       "profile_photos"."createdAt" AS "profile_photos.createdAt",
       "profile_photos"."updatedAt" AS "profile_photos.updatedAt",
       "documents"."id" AS "documents.id",
       "documents"."user_id" AS "documents.user_id",
       "documents"."url" AS "documents.url",
       "documents"."type" AS "documents.type",
       "documents"."case_id" AS "documents.case_id",
       "documents"."createdAt" AS "documents.createdAt",
       "documents"."updatedAt" AS "documents.updatedAt",
       "referees"."id" AS "referees.id",
       "referees"."first_name" AS "referees.first_name",
       "referees"."last_name" AS "referees.last_name",
       "referees"."email" AS "referees.email",
       "referees"."phone" AS "referees.phone",
       "referees"."role" AS "referees.role",
       "referees"."job_venue" AS "referees.job_venue",
       "referees"."gig_worker_id" AS "referees.gig_worker_id",
       "referees"."assessment_given" AS "referees.assessment_given",
       "referees"."gig_worker_assessment" AS "referees.gig_worker_assessment",
       "referees"."score" AS "referees.score",
       "referees"."createdAt" AS "referees.createdAt",
       "referees"."updatedAt" AS "referees.updatedAt",
       "ratings"."id" AS "ratings.id",
       "ratings"."gig_id" AS "ratings.gig_id",
       "ratings"."business_id" AS "ratings.business_id",
       "ratings"."gig_worker_id" AS "ratings.gig_worker_id",
       "ratings"."type" AS "ratings.type",
       "ratings"."rating" AS "ratings.rating",
       "ratings"."evaluation" AS "ratings.evaluation",
       "ratings"."review" AS "ratings.review",
       "ratings"."assessment_given" AS "ratings.assessment_given",
       "ratings"."createdAt" AS "ratings.createdAt",
       "ratings"."updatedAt" AS "ratings.updatedAt"
FROM
  (SELECT "gig_workers"."id",
          "gig_workers"."user_id",
          "gig_workers"."first_name",
          "gig_workers"."last_name",
          "gig_workers"."address",
          "gig_workers"."contact_number",
          "gig_workers"."profile_picture",
          "gig_workers"."work_rights",
          "gig_workers"."status",
          "gig_workers"."verified",
          "gig_workers"."available_time",
          "gig_workers"."license",
          "gig_workers"."venue_experience",
          "gig_workers"."certification",
          "gig_workers"."language",
          "gig_workers"."latitude",
          "gig_workers"."longitude",
          "gig_workers"."radius",
          "gig_workers"."createdAt",
          "gig_workers"."updatedAt",
          AVG("ratings"."rating") AS "avgRatings"
   FROM "gig_workers" AS "gig_workers"
   GROUP BY "gig_workers"."id"
   LIMIT 30
   OFFSET 0) AS "gig_workers"
LEFT OUTER JOIN ("gig_worker_type_rels" AS "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"
                 INNER JOIN "gig_types" AS "gig_types" ON "gig_types"."id" = "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"."gigTypeId") ON "gig_workers"."id" = "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"."gigWorkerId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "gig_worker_metas" AS "gig_worker_metas" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "gig_worker_metas"."gig_worker_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "profile_photos" AS "profile_photos" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "profile_photos"."case_id"
AND "profile_photos"."type" = 'profile'
LEFT OUTER JOIN "documents" AS "documents" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "documents"."case_id"
AND "documents"."type" = 'profile'
LEFT OUTER JOIN "referees" AS "referees" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "referees"."gig_worker_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "ratings" AS "ratings" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "ratings"."gig_worker_id";
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY`, `LIMIT`, and `OFFSET` clauses are in the wrong place. There are also numerous other syntax errors in the query.

Comment: @JohnH The `GROUP BY`, `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses are in a subquery. Why is that the wrong place?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the query. Readability would be greatly improved by formatting, reducing the excessive use of quoted identifiers, and eliminating redundant aliasing. Using actual table names as subquery aliases can also make queries more difficult to read. In this case I saw the `"gig_workers"` alias for the subquery and failed to notice the redundant aliasing of `"gig_workers"` prior to the `GROUP BY` (a result of years of working with teams that eschew such aliasing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within this subquery. It selects `AVG("ratings"."rating")` but fails to mention the `ratings` relation in its `FROM` clause:

```
    SELECT
          "gig_workers"."id",
          "gig_workers"."user_id",
          "gig_workers"."first_name",
          "gig_workers"."last_name",
          "gig_workers"."address",
          "gig_workers"."contact_number",
          "gig_workers"."profile_picture",
          "gig_workers"."work_rights",
          "gig_workers"."status",
          "gig_workers"."verified",
          "gig_workers"."available_time",
          "gig_workers"."license",
          "gig_workers"."venue_experience",
          "gig_workers"."certification",
          "gig_workers"."language",
          "gig_workers"."latitude",
          "gig_workers"."longitude",
          "gig_workers"."radius",
          "gig_workers"."createdAt",
          "gig_workers"."updatedAt",
          AVG("ratings"."rating") AS "avgRatings"
   FROM "gig_workers" AS "gig_workers"
   GROUP BY "gig_workers"."id"
   LIMIT 30
   OFFSET 0
```

I highly recommend using a formatting tool like https://sqlformat.org/ to format your SQL queries. It will be much easier to work with them and error messages are much more meaningful because the line mentioned in the error message contains less code.

Comment: Also, if you have a GROUP BY then every column in your SELECT must either be an aggregate function or also be in the GROUP BY - so all those "gig_workers" columns need to be in your GROUP BY

Comment: @NickW That is not necessarily true. If `id` is the primary key it is valid SQL to select any column. See ["Why can I select all fields when grouping by primary key"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158015/why-can-i-select-all-fields-when-grouping-by-primary-key-but-not-when-grouping-b).